# Have "APP" as prefix and then allow only numbers in input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngx-mask

I have a requirement where I have an input field, that must have the prefix "APP " and then allow the user to type in 7 numeric only values. I was hoping I could use ngx-mask, but it doesn't seem possible. Alternatively I was thinking of using (focusin) event like:

```
(focusin)="addPrefix($event)"

inputValue = "";
addPrefix(ev: any){
 inputValue = "APP ";
}
```

and then having a keyup event which would disregard key presses if input.length <= 3.But then comes this issue of pasting values in. Does anyone else have any better ideas/suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You should probably add more relevant tags-- this is clearly beyond simple [tag:html] with no JS framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mask-eisqcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

How about,

```
<input type="text" prefix="APP " mask="0000000" [clearIfNotMatch]="true" />
```

using ngx-mask?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed the prefix property in the docs. Thanks alot!